# Replace values in a data table based on several columns in lookup table

Tags: r

Given a data table `df` with among others, a code column and a version column, I would like to replace the values in the code column based on a lookup table `look`.

```
df <- data.table(structure(list(year = c("1951", "1951", "1951", "1951", "1951"),
                     region = c(10, 11, 12, 18, 4),
                     code = c("140", "140", "140","1403", "1404"),
                     version = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 9)), row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

year region code version
1: 1951     10  140       6
2: 1951     11  140       7
3: 1951     12  140       8
4: 1951     18 1403       9
5: 1951      4 1404       9
```

```
look <- data.table(structure(list(code = c("C00", "C000", "C001", "C002", "C003","C004"),
                                  ver67 = c(140L, 1400L, 1401L, NA, NA, NA),
                                  ver8 = c(140L,1400L, 1401L, NA, NA, NA),
                                  ver9 = c(140L, 1400L, 1401L, NA, 1403L,1404L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))

code ver67 ver8 ver9
1:  C00   140  140  140
2: C000  1400 1400 1400
3: C001  1401 1401 1401
4: C002    NA   NA   NA
5: C003    NA   NA 1403
6: C004    NA   NA 1404
```

So that the code values of `df` is replaced with the code values of `look` when matching the code and corresponding version, as below.

```
year region code
1: 1951     10  C00
2: 1951     11  C00
3: 1951     12  C00
4: 1951     18 C003
5: 1951      4 C004
```

I am not quite sure how to tackle this challenge and would love some inputs to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest, to first transform your lookup-table into a long-format table, and then use `left_join` to join the lookup-values to the table (assuming you are fine with using tidyverse, and not sticking that much to data.table):

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

look_long <- look %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("ver"), names_to = "ver") %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(ver = str_split(str_remove(ver, "ver"), "")) %>%
  unnest(ver) %>%
  transmute(ver = as.integer(ver),
            value = as.character(value),
            newcode = code)

df %>%
  left_join(look_long, by = c("code" = "value", "version" = "ver"))
#>    year region code version newcode
#> 1: 1951     10  140       6     C00
#> 2: 1951     11  140       7     C00
#> 3: 1951     12  140       8     C00
#> 4: 1951     18 1403       9    C003
#> 5: 1951      4 1404       9    C004
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>